# Apollo-Server typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got ${typeof typeSource}

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

**TypeDefs**
*indexTypes.js*

> const path = require('path');
> const {loadFilesSync} = require('@graphql-tools/load-files');
> const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
> const {mergeTypeDefs} = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
>
> const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, './'), {
> recursive: true, extensions: ['.js'] });
> const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray, {all: true});
> const typedefs = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs});
>
> module.exports = {typedefs};

**Resolvers**
*indexResolvers.js*

> const path = require('path');
> const { loadFilesSync } = require('@graphql-tools/load-files');
> const { mergeResolvers } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
>
> const resolversArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, './'), {
> recursive: true,   extensions: ['.js'], });
>
> const resolvers = mergeResolvers(resolversArray);
>
> module.exports = { resolvers };

**index.js**

> const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server');
> const express = require('express'); require('dotenv').config(); require('./utils/db');
> const port = process.env.PORT;
> const {typedefs} = require('./graphql/schema/indexTypes');
> const {resolvers} = require('./graphql/resolvers/indexResolvers');
>
> const app = express();
>
> const server = new ApolloServer({
> typedefs,
> resolvers, });
>
> server.listen(port) .then(({ url }) => {   console.log( `Server is ready at ${url}`); }) .catch((e) => {   console.log('⚡ Cannot launch
> server:', e.message); });

**Error message**
Error: typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got object
at visitTypeSources

Comment: Have you tried console logging the results of each step in your typedef composition? Is the makeExecutableSchema function able to run if the mergeTypeDefs step is skipped (e.g. if only the visitTypeSources schema is loaded)? This seems like an issue with one of the schemas being merged in.